# (Angular 5+) Getting data from child routes

Tags: angular, angular-router

I want to make breadcrumb for my app, so I put "title" on my data routes like this one:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },    
    {path: 'help', component: HelpComponent },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
        data: { title: "Admin"},
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'organisation', 
                component: ListOrganizationComponent, 
                data:{title: "Organisation"}, 
                resolve: {organizations: ListOrganizationResolver}
            }        
        ]
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
    title: string = "";
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.title = this.route.snapshot.data.title;
    }
}
```

When I run the code and go to: `localhost:4200/admin/organisation` 
only title from admin show up (title = "Admin"). I want to get title Organisation from child route .. how to do that ?
And is there easy way to make breadcrumb in angular ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [firstChild](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#firstChild) property on your ActivatedRoute to retrieve the `firstChild` route and then go ahead and retrieve the data as you would for the current route. Here's an example:

```
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  breadcrumb: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    let breadcrumb = this.route.snapshot.data['title'];

    if (this.route.snapshot.firstChild) {
        breadcrumb += ' > ' + this.route.snapshot.firstChild.data['title'];
    }

    this.breadcrumb = breadcrumb;
  }

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
}
```

Here's a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spvn8n). Be sure to navigate to `/admin/organization`.

For your second question, you could try out [ngx-breadcrumbs](https://github.com/McNull/ngx-breadcrumbs) as the other answer mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, i have used **[`ngx-breadcrumbs`](https://github.com/McNull/ngx-breadcrumbs)** which is easily configurable and you do not have to do anything out of the box.

**`npm --save install ngx-breadcrumbs`**